# c++ trying to initialize objects of a class I wrote in a for loop

Tags: c++, object, initialization

this may be a very basic c++ question but I am a bit rusty. I am trying to set up a maze type data structure with points. Here is my code.

```
class Point{

    public :

    int xCoord;
    int yCoord;
    bool visited;

    //constructors
    Point(){}
    Point(int x, int y){
        xCoord = x;
        yCoord = y;
        visited = false;
    }
    int makeVisited(){
        visited = true;
    }

    int makeUnvisited(){
        visited = false;
    }
};



class Maze{

    public :

    int width;
    int height;
    Point ** grid; 

    //constructors
    Maze(){}
    Maze(int X, int Y){
        width = X;
        height = Y;
        grid = new Point*[width];
        for(int i = 0; i < width; i++){
            grid[i] = new Point[height];
            for(int j = 0; j < height; j++){
                grid[i][j] = new Point(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
}; //end of Maze class
```

When I try to asign grid[i][j] a new point instance, I get an error saying

"error no operator "=" matches these operands"

Can someone tell me what I did wrong with the initialization of the point object?

Comment: Stop using pointers for this and consider using `std::vector<std::vector<Point> >`.

Comment: Isn't makeVisited() and makeUnvisited() supposed to return an int?  Otherwise change them to void.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `grid` is declared as a `Point**`, then `grid[i][j]` is of type `Point`. So you can't assign a `new Point` to this.

---

One thing you can do is to define a setter member function, like:

```
void Point::set(int x, int y) {
  xCoord = x;
  yCoord = y;
}
```

And then in your loop you can use:

```
grid[i][j].set(i, j);
```

Comment: A setter method like this is silly. Just use plain old assignment. That's what it's for. Compounding Java thinking with yet more Java thinking...

Comment: Now that fixed things, I think I will go with that. However, one last thing, I now have an error of "incomplete types are not allowed"

Comment: when I try and declare a maze like 

    Maze main_maze

**edit, nvmd fixed it. Thanks Guys!

Comment: @Omnifarious I'm not sure why you accuse me of Java thinking. Did you look at my profile?

Comment: @chrisaycock: Ahh, no. So apparently that's not where your predilection for 'setter' methods comes from. :-) I tend to really dislike those tiny little methods most of the time because they're an indication of poor design. And in this case I think they obscure the fact that you're basically doing simple assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop should look like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < width; i++){
    grid[i] = new Point[height];
    for(int j = 0; j < height; j++){
        grid[i][j] = Point(i, j);
    }
}
```

Your array contains all its points by value, it doesn't contain pointers to them. I think that's the right design choice on your part. But that means that you don't try to put pointers in there. The type of `grid[i][j]` is `Point`, not `Point *`. The `new` operator will allocate space for a `Point` object on the heap and return a `Point *` pointing to it. But you already have a perfectly fine `Point` object in your array already.

Your code looks like you're used to Java. In C++ you can actually contain values directly instead of always having references to them. All of your points are actually initialized using their default constructors in the line that reads `grid[i] = new Point[height];`. There you create `height` `Point` objects and each of their default constructors is called to initialize them.

If you use my code, you then later re-assign their values from a temporary `Point` object. This object's creation will be optimized out of existence by the compiler and it will simply turn into assigning the new `xCoord` and `yCoord` values of the already existing `Point` directly from `i` and `j`.

Comment: how would i fix my code then? That is initially what i wanted to do.

Comment: @Zack: Your code will be just fine if you use the version of the `for` loop I suggest. Creating all of these tiny `Point` objects on the heap with `new` will result in a lot of efficiency problems and no locality of reference.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you need Point ***grid, coz you obviously want to have 2 dim array storing pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is pointing out that you do not have an assignment operator for the class.  You will have to define an 'operator=' method to achieve what you are trying to do.  You are also better to use vectors in this instance.